# walletconnect doesn't work in localhost but in codesandbox using web3-react

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, wallet-connect, web3-react

i tried to implement walletconnect using web3-react follow by their example in docs, but seem like it's doesn't work in localhost but codesandbox. Can someone explain to me how can it happened, my simple codesandbox to refer
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-dj3tr?file=/src/connectors/walletConnect.ts

Answer (score 0):

Using https `getSubtleCrypto` function in WalletConnect returns `global.crypto.subtle` and in the insecure mode http, it's undefined.

https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal/issues/334